# Openx: delete all statistics

Tags: php, openx

What tables shall I empty to delete all my statistics (openx 2.6.2)?

(My maintenance.php can't run in 300s max execution time so, right now, I just to keep my zones, websites, etc and just prune all the stats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Openx 2.6, all banner requests logged into `data_raw_ad_request` table and all impressions logged into `data_raw_ad_impression` table.

If you really want to delete all request & impression counts, you can truncate these 2 tables.